# Maven created jar to android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, maven, jar

I have exported a jar file from one of my maven projects. This project has a dependency of apache common validations. after I have added the jar to libs folder of my android project, and also I have added the common validations jar files (made sure that they are in the same version both in the maven project and in the android project). Now when I run the app I am getting this error:

```
01-24 20:58:14.151: E/AndroidRuntime(1241): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-24 20:58:14.151: E/AndroidRuntime(1241): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.evappcom.validator.Validator
01-24 20:58:14.151: E/AndroidRuntime(1241):     at com.evapp.protocols.BaseProtocol.emailValidation(BaseProtocol.java:176)
01-24 20:58:14.151: E/AndroidRuntime(1241):     at com.evapp.protocols.PasswordLoginProtocol.isValidInput(PasswordLoginProtocol.java:30)
01-24 20:58:14.151: E/AndroidRuntime(1241):     at com.evapp.activities.LoginActivity.doLogin(LoginActivity.java:88)
01-24 20:58:14.151: E/AndroidRuntime(1241):     at com.evapp.activities.LoginActivity.access$0(LoginActivity.java:82)
01-24 20:58:14.151: E/AndroidRuntime(1241):     at com.evapp.activities.LoginActivity$1.onClick(LoginActivity.java:56)
01-24 20:58:14.151: E/AndroidRuntime(1241):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
01-24 20:58:14.151: E/AndroidRuntime(1241):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
01-24 20:58:14.151: E/AndroidRuntime(1241):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
01-24 20:58:14.151: E/AndroidRuntime(1241):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-24 20:58:14.151: E/AndroidRuntime(1241):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-24 20:58:14.151: E/AndroidRuntime(1241):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
01-24 20:58:14.151: E/AndroidRuntime(1241):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-24 20:58:14.151: E/AndroidRuntime(1241):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-24 20:58:14.151: E/AndroidRuntime(1241):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
01-24 20:58:14.151: E/AndroidRuntime(1241):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
01-24 20:58:14.151: E/AndroidRuntime(1241):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-24 20:58:47.347: E/Trace(1258): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
```

What is wrong with my process?

Comment: What this mean *both in the maven project and in the android project*. This should be one maven android project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't export jar file from maven project. Use maven command:

```
mvn package
```

to build android applications and copy it form `target` directory.

Comment: I am receiving an error while executing this command: `[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project evappcom: Fatal error compiling: invalid target release: 1.7 -> [Help 1]`

Comment: target 1.7 requires JDK 1.7, check `java -version`

Comment: I managed to run `mvn package`, but there is nothing in the target folder.

Comment: found it, will try to add it to android

Comment: Still android crashes with the new added jar... :(

Comment: Your libraries are configured inside `pom.xml`?

Comment: The same error, yes inside pom.xml:
`<dependency>
   <groupId>commons-validator</groupId>
   <artifactId>commons-validator</artifactId>
   <version>1.3.1</version>`
  </dependency

Comment: Your project is using `android-maven-plugin`?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46048/discussion-between-vlad-ioffe-and-mariuszs)